# How do I re-base this in gerrit?

Tags: gerrit

I have the following case in gerrit,

```
(master)O---C1---C2---C4
             \
              C3
```

Now there are two files F1 and F2 that are common files in C1 and C2 commits but different contents. Also there is other file F3 that is common in C1 and C3 commits.

Now these changes have not yet been reviewed. Now this has resulted in merge conflict. How can I resolve this ?

Comment: Which changes are already merged and which are still open? Which change has a merge conflict?

Comment: Well nothing has been merged. Currently gerrit  shows cannot merge for C4 and C3